# Heap allocation keeps increasing by big chunks, GC unable to free memory comparatively

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I am working with an android app, on triggering some key events repeatedly, memory keeps getting allocated on heap in considerable chunks,

while GC is not able to free un-allocated memory, but keeps freeing small amounts.

On calling system.gc() explicitly, it quickly frees the memory, so i can confirm that memory is indeed de-referenced.

I understand that GC frees heap memory when it thinks it needs to reclaim memory but in this scenario, GC seems a bit too lazy, causing app allocations to keep rising upto ~1 GB and then android kills the app.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a question. But general ideas such as trying to minimize allocation/deallocation of objects, pool, and such can help to reduce memory spikes.

Comment: I am trying to perform some events quickly, each such event creates a considerable chunk of memory on heap, if these events continue and gc doesn't kick in, i wonder if there is a way to control an outOfMemory situation.

Comment: So you have two questions? What can you do to minimize memory consumption? How can you control outOfMemory? Perhaps you should add these to the original questions so it's clear.

Comment: No i don't intend to reduce memory consumption, i need to reduce memory consumption footprint, by gc compensating for spike in allocations, and avoid outOfMemory too :)

Comment: It's not very Java-like to want to have control over garbage collection. It is far better to try to improve your code and reduce the spikes in memory allocation/deallocation all together.